# Simple Excel Question: VLookup Error

Tags: data-cleaning

My data looks like this:

[image]

Why is this error showing up?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common result of imprecise matching, such as with whitespace problems.

For example, if you imagine that the grey shading used in codeblocks on StackExchange represents the whitespaces in your Excel cells, then 
  `AK` 
is technically the same as

```
AK
```

You can trim and/or use wildcard chars to allow matching to skip spaces. For example:

`=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE("*",TRIM(A2),"*"), $E$2:$F$5, 2,FALSE)`

Comment: I've looked for spaces after each of the state names. There aren't any.